# Tangent line to a concave down function is greater than the function proof?

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f(3)=2, f'(3)=0.5$, also $f'(x)>0$ and $f''(x)<0$ on all real number x.

It makes sense intuitively and graphically, but how do I prove rigorously that the tangent line $L$ of $f(x)$ at $x=3$ is greater than or equal to $f(x)$ at all x?